# Get updated property file tags without server restart java

Tags: java, jsp

I have a property file which has a field date, which is used in jsp logic. I need to have an option to modify those dates and get reflected in jsp without server restart.
For example - I need to block content of jsp page on suppose 3 dates and I want to have flexibility to modify.
I have tried hard coding the dates in properties file and it works but the change in property file doea not reflects without server restart which is not preferrable, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: which server are u using?

Comment: Post your code where you're loading properties file.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill in your situation, but since the dates seem to change unrelated to the deployment/maintenance cycle of the system you could very well consider to treat it like normal data in a database table.

Comment: That would be way simpler and more powerful than a simple properties file, if the performance impact is not too much. +1

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the big guns (storing data in a database) as @midin suggested, this is what comes to mind:

- store values in a jsp and include that. As this would be recompiled on the fly your new values would be active after save.
- store values in external (from your webapp) file and re-read every so often
- use a Preferences object in the app-servers context
- if you **have** a database connected to your app already: use that.